# Can't delete a user in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I wanted to delete a user but, when i clicked the trash (delete) icon. I've got a fully blank page which is the problem i'm facing. I've tried a lot of things on this but, I'm facing the same issue. I think it's not in the database user is the problem maybe in the code.
                        Here is my php codes.

```
//dash.php
 <?php
     if(@$_GET['q']==1) {

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user") or die('Error');
        echo  '<div class="panel"><div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-striped title1">
        <tr><td><b>S.N.</b></td><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Gender</b></td><td><b>College</b></td><td><b>Course</b></td><td><b>Email</b></td><td><b>Mobile</b></td><td></td></tr>';
        $c=1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $name = $row['name'];
            $mob = $row['mob'];
            $gender = $row['gender'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $college = $row['college'];
          $course = $row['course'];

            echo '<tr><td>'.$c++.'</td><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$gender.'</td><td>'.$college.'
</td><td>'.$course.'</td><td>'.$email.'</td><td>'.$mob.'</td>
            <td><a title="Delete User" href="update.php?demail='.$email.'">
<b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></b></a></td></tr>';
        }
        $c=0;
        echo '</table></div></div>';

        }
        ?>


            //update.php
            <?php
            include_once 'dbConnection.php';
            session_start();
            $email=$_SESSION['email'];
            //delete feedback
            if(isset($_SESSION['key'])){
            if(@$_GET['fdid'] && $_SESSION['key']=='bondad7785068889') {
            $id=@$_GET['fdid'];
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM feedback WHERE id='$id' ") or die('Error');
            header("location:dash.php?q=3");
            }
            }


            //delete user

            if(isset($_SESSION['key'])){
            if(@$_GET['demail'] && $_SESSION['key']=='bondad7785068889') {
            $demail=@$_GET['demail'];
            $r1 = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM rank WHERE email='$demail' ") or die('Error');
            $r2 = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM history WHERE email='$demail' ") or die('Error');
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM user WHERE email='$demail' ") or die('Error');
            header("location:dash.php?q=1");
            }
            }
            ?>


             //dbConnection.php
```

Here are the screenshots:

[Here is the screenshot of the users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoBFJ.png)

[Blank Page (error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZj6P.png)

[Inside the database table : users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQS11.png)

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You need to use error reporting when developing. `die('Error')` will never help you, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thanks for the responses sir.